# Overriding some methods from abstract class WebElementFacade

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, overriding, abstract-class

Testing with Selenium on an Angular site may be tricky, as webDriver finds it difficult to know when all the asynchronous processes have finished, before it interacts with elements.

I fixed this by writing an actions class in which I waited for Angular before carrying out the actions (click, fill, check etc.) using [Paul Hammants ngWebDriver](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver) (Java):

```
import com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.NgWebDriver;

public class ActionsWithWaits {

    private NgWebDriver ngdriver;
    private JavascriptExecutor js;

    public ActionsWithWaits(){
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ngdriver = new NgWebDriver(js);
    }


    public void waitForAngular(){
        ngdriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
    }

    public void waitAndClick(WebElementFacade button){
        waitForAngular();
        button.click();
    }

    public void waitAndFillIn(String text, WebElementFacade field){
        waitForAngular();
        field.type(text);
    }
```

etc..
I now use those actions instead of the standard WebElement(Facade) methods (click(),type() etc.) and it works fine.

However, I have a feeling that it can be more elegant, for example by overriding those WebElementFacade methods. (So that they will first perform my waitForAngular, and then just click -or type, or whatever- like normal)

I tried several things, like extending WebElementFacade, but this is an abstract class, so then I would have to implement it, which comes along with many other difficulties...

I am a newbie so I kind of got stuck here.. I just want to override a few of those methods. Does anyone have suggestions about how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know, which class is extending the WebElementFacade? Maybe you can extend from that class?

Comment: Thanks to your comment I've found some advice about this on [this google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/thucydides-users/8LD7Y9d3T1U). I'm currently trying to implement this, I'll keep you posted!